# Dockerfile Maven Plugin: Failure to find plugin

Tags: java, maven, docker, dockerfile, maven-plugin

I want to use the plugin "Dockerfile Maven" to build docker images from my project. When I add this plugin into my pom.xml

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
  <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${dockerfile-maven-version}</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>default</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>build</goal>
        <goal>push</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <repository>spotify/foobar</repository>
    <tag>${project.version}</tag>
    <buildArgs>
      <JAR_FILE>${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
    </buildArgs>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I am getting an error on the first line of my pom:

```
Failure to find com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-plugin:jar:${dockerfile-maven-version} in https://
 repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the 
 update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
```

Do I need to configure something? I can't find anyone with the same problem. This is my pom.xml configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>de.leuphana</groupId>
    <artifactId>ArticleMicroService</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ArticleMicroService</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where did you define the value for variable`dockerfile-maven-version`?

You should add it to the properties

```
 <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
        <dockerfile-maven-version>1.4.10</dockerfile-maven-version>
 </properties>
```

Comment: that solved it. Thank you! Why isnt this displayed in the readme in GitHub?

Comment: I think they don't want to have a hard coded version in the README.md. But yes, the description could be extended by saying that you have to put the required version in the properties. Maybe you want to open a pull request on github or open an issue for that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to define dockerfile-maven-version in the  section of your POM

Add to properties:

```
<dockerfile-maven-version>1.4.10</dockerfile-maven-version>
```